# Pulsate text CSS3 only?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to make a pulsating text effect where given a string of text "Hello World", every few seconds it eases from green to blue, then blue to green, green to blue, blue to green without a single line of javascript? (does there happen to be any SCSS or SASS shortcuts?)

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried / what do you think that's a good start?

Comment: Did any of the solutions help? Please select an answer if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the CSS3 for what you want:

```css
.textClass {
 -webkit-animation: color_change 1s infinite alternate;
 -moz-animation: color_change 1s infinite alternate;
 -ms-animation: color_change 1s infinite alternate;
 -o-animation: color_change 1s infinite alternate;
 animation: color_change 1s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
 from { color: blue; }
 to { color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes color_change {
 from { color: blue; }
 to { color: green; }
}
@-ms-keyframes color_change {
 from { color: blue; }
 to { color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes color_change {
 from { color: blue; }
 to { color: green; }
}
@keyframes color_change {
 from { color: blue; }
 to { color: green; }
}
```

```html
<p class="textClass">Hello World</p>
```

Read: http://tjvantoll.com/2012/02/20/CSS3-Color-Animations/ for more info

Comment: +1, but the code could be compacted. First, the `-ms-` version is not necessary, it was only necessary for early IE10 previews. IE9 does not support animations and IE10 supports them unprefixed. Also, you could write the `color: blue` in the `.textClass` and omit the `from` keyframe (it's going to be automaticlly generated from what you have in the class).

Answer (score 5):

Yep:

```css
@keyframes textColorChange {
    0% {color: #0000ff;}
    50% {color: #00ff00;}
    100% {color: #0000ff;}
}
/* Use @-webkit-keyframes for Safari/Chrome */

#textElement {
    animation: textColorChange 2s infinite;
}
/* Use -webkit-animation for Safari/Chrome */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**CSS:**

```css
@-webkit-keyframes altrclr{
  0%{
    color:red;
  }
  50%{
    color:green;
  }
}

#a{
  margin:40%;
  font-size:20px;
  color:red;
  -webkit-animation: altrclr 3s infinite alternate;  
  -webkit-transform:scale(4);
}
```

**Html**

```html
<div id='a'>
    Hello World
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/anijom/1)**

Comment: Please don't use just WebKit prefixes. Especially not when the unprefixed syntax is supported by current versions of all other major browsers - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation